# Error de email existente no se refleja en campo de formulario

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

¡Buenas a todos!

Estoy aprendiendo PHP y la verdad que soy bastante verde, ahora mismo hago un "login" con nombre, correo, contraseña y contraseña repetida al registrarse todo funciona bien. Pero si intento registrar con un email ya existente, debería mostrar un error en el formulario "Este correo ya está registrado" pero deja página en blanco.

**PHP PDO register.php**

```
<?php

define('DB_SERVER', 'localhost');
define('DB_USERNAME', 'root');
define('DB_PASSWORD', '');
define('DB_NAME', 'pruebas');
/* Intentamos connectar a la base de datos*/
try {
    $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=" . DB_SERVER . ";dbname=" . DB_NAME, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD);
    // cambiamos idioma de datos al resibir desde la base de datos
    $acentos = $pdo->query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");

    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    die("ERROR: No se puede connectar. " . $e->getMessage());
}
 
// definimos parametros sin valor
$username = $password = $confirm_password = $email = $email_verification = "";
$username_err = $password_err = $confirm_password_err = $email_err = "";
 
// Recibimos metodo POST cuando esta enviado
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
 
    // Validacion de email
    if (empty(trim($_POST["email"]))) {
        $email_err = "Por favor introduzca su correo.";
    } else {
        //   Preparamos statement
        $sql = "SELECT id_user FROM users WHERE email_user = :email";
        
        if ($stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql)) {
            // Vinculamos parametros
            $stmt->bindParam(":email", $param_email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            
            // Ejecutamos
            if ($stmt->execute()) {
                if ($stmt->rowCount() == 1) {
                    $email_err = "Este correo ya esta registrado.";
                } else {
                    $email = trim($_POST["email"]);
                }
            } else {
                echo "Ooops! Algo va mal, contact con el administrador.";
            }

            // Cerramos statement
            unset($stmt);
        }
    }
    // Validacion de nombre de usuario
    $username = trim($_POST["username"]);
    if (empty($username)) {
        $username_err = "Please enter a name.";
    } elseif (!filter_var($username, FILTER_VALIDATE_REGEXP, array("options"=>array("regexp"=>"/^[a-zA-Z\s]+$/")))) {
        $username_err = "Please enter a valid name.";
    } else {
        $username = $username;
    }
    
    // Validacion de contraseña
    if (empty(trim($_POST["password"]))) {
        $password_err = "Please enter a password.";
    } elseif (strlen(trim($_POST["password"])) < 6) {
        $password_err = "Contraseña tiene que tener al menos 6 caracteres.";
    } else {
        $password = trim($_POST["password"]);
    }

    // Validacion de segundo contraseña
    if (empty(trim($_POST["confirm_password"]))) {
        $confirm_password_err = "Por favor, confirme la contraseña.";
    } else {
        $confirm_password = trim($_POST["confirm_password"]);
        if (empty($password_err) && ($password != $confirm_password)) {
            $confirm_password_err = "Contraseñas no conciden.";
        }
    }
    //Codigo de confirmacion de email
    $email_verification = rand(100000, 999999);
    
    // revisamos errors existentes antes de insertar a la base de datos
    if (empty($username_err)&& empty($email_err) && empty($password_err) && empty($confirm_password_err)) {
       
        // Preparamos INSERT en USERS
        $sql = "INSERT INTO users (username, email_user, password, email_verification) VALUES (:username, :email, :password, :email_verification)";
    
        if ($stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql)) {
            // Bind variables en prepared statement as parameters
            $stmt->bindParam(":username", $param_username, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->bindParam(":email", $param_email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->bindParam(":password", $param_password, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->bindParam(":email_verification", $param_email_verification, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            
            // Set parameters
            $param_username = $username;
            $param_email = $email;
            $param_email_verification = $email_verification;
            $param_password = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT); // Creates a password hash
            
            //Intentamos ejecutar the prepared statement
            if ($stmt->execute()) {
                // Redirecion despues de registrar
                header("location: login.php");
            } else {
                echo "Algo no va bien, intentelo de nuevo o contacte con nosotros.";
            }

            // Cerramos statement
            unset($stmt);
        }
    }
    
    // cerramos connecion
    unset($pdo);
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Sign Up</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <style>
    body {
        font: 14px sans-serif;
    }

    .wrapper {
        width: 360px;
        padding: 20px;
    }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <h2>Registrate</h2>
        <p>Por favor, rellene los campos para registrarse.</p>
        <form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>" method="post">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Nombre</label>
                <input type="text" name="username"
                    class="form-control <?php echo (!empty($username_err)) ? 'is-invalid' : ''; ?>"
                    value="<?php echo $username; ?>">
                <span class="invalid-feedback"><?php echo $username_err; ?></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Correo electronico</label>
                <input type="email" name="email"
                    class="form-control <?php echo (!empty($email_err)) ? 'is-invalid' : ''; ?>"
                    value="<?php echo $email; ?>">
                <span class="invalid-feedback"><?php echo $email_err; ?></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Contraseña</label>
                <input type="password" name="password"
                    class="form-control <?php echo (!empty($password_err)) ? 'is-invalid' : ''; ?>"
                    value="<?php echo $password; ?>">
                <span class="invalid-feedback"><?php echo $password_err; ?></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Confirme la contraseña</label>
                <input type="password" name="confirm_password"
                    class="form-control <?php echo (!empty($confirm_password_err)) ? 'is-invalid' : ''; ?>"
                    value="<?php echo $confirm_password; ?>">
                <span class="invalid-feedback"><?php echo $confirm_password_err; ?></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Enviar">
                <input type="reset" class="btn btn-secondary ml-2" value="Reset">
            </div>
            <p>Ya estas registrado? <a href="login.php">Login</a>.</p>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

en la línea 38 se realiza revisión de existencia de este correo

```
if ($stmt->execute()) {
                if ($stmt->rowCount() == 1) {
                    $email_err = "Este correo ya esta registrado.";
                } else {
                    $email = trim($_POST["email"]);
                }
```

y si correo existe, debería recibir mensaje en el mismo formulario con el aviso, pero no lo imprime (ejemplo de error cuando email no está introducido)
[image: Como debería verse el mensaje de error]

---

Solo marca error en consola:

> Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry 'jaime@gmail.com' for key 'email_user' in D:\TimeTracking\register.php:89

¡Un saludo y **gracias** por adelantado!

Comment: Pues no se ve en qué momento inicializas `$param_email`, que es lo que usas en el SELECT para validar. Posiblemente está vacío, no hay registros con email vacío y avanza con la inserción.

Comment: No lo inicializo en la línea 34 
``` $stmt->bindParam(":email", $param_email, PDO::PARAM_STR); ```

Comment: Como que no te realiza la comprobación? Si es exactamente lo que está haciendo... está diciéndote que has intentado insertar un valor repetido en una clave única, ergo, ese email ya existe. Eso es lo que significa tu error... literalmente.

Comment: Si, pero deja la página en blanco en vez de publicar el error en la parte de formulario con texto en rojo

Comment: Tienes toda la razón mi problema no está bien explicada en el post, voy a editarlo

Comment: No es correcto. estás diciéndole al stmt que donde vea `:email` en la sentencia SQL, use `$param_email`, pero en ninguna parte le asignas algo a `$param_email` antes de eso.

Comment: @Alfabravo **Gracias!** Pude solucionarlo con tu observación ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que $param_email no existe en esta linea

```
if ($stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql)) {
    // Vinculamos parametros
    $stmt->bindParam(":email", $param_email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

Se debe recoger `$param_email` antes con `$param_email = $_POST['email'];` para que entonces pueda ser utilizada.

Lo siguiente puede ser una opinión, pero veo el código un poco enredado. Podría mejorarse mucho usando **funciones** o una **class**. Pero si no quieres usar ninguna, una forma más organizada del mismo, en la parte del `if` principal, sería:

```
<?php
// ...
// Lo anterior a esto se queda igual
// Recibimos metodo POST cuando esta enviado
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    $username = trim($_POST["username"]);
    $filtered_username = filter_var($username, FILTER_VALIDATE_REGEXP, 
                        array("options"=>array("regexp"=>"/^[a-zA-Z\s]+$/")));
    $email = trim($_POST["email"]);
    $filtered_email = filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL, FILTER_NULL_ON_FAILURE);
    $password = $_POST["password"];
    $confirm_password = $_POST["confirm_password"];

    if(empty($username)) {
        $username_err = "Please enter a name.";
    } elseif (!$filtered_username) {
        $username_err = "Please enter a valid name.";
    } elseif(!$filtered_email) {
        $email_err = "Por favor introduzca un correo valido.";
    } elseif(empty($password)) {
        $password_err = "Please enter a password.";
    } elseif(strlen($password) < 6) {
        $password_err = "Contraseña tiene que tener al menos 6 caracteres.";
    } elseif(empty($confirm_password)) {
        $confirm_password_err = "Por favor, confirme la contraseña.";
    } elseif($password !== $confirm_password) {
        $confirm_password_err = "Contraseñas no conciden.";
    } else {
        //Codigo de confirmacion de email
        $email_verification = rand(100000, 999999);
        $sql = "SELECT id_user FROM users WHERE email_user = :email";
        $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bindParam(":email", $filtered_email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->execute();
        if($stmt->rowCount() > 0) {
            $email_err = "Este correo ya esta registrado.";
        } else {
            $stmt->closeCursor(); // Limpiar el stmt de la consulta anterior
            $sql = "INSERT INTO users (username, email_user, password, email_verification) 
            VALUES (:username, :email, :password, :email_verification)";
            $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
            $stmt->bindParam(":username", $param_username, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->bindParam(":email", $param_email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->bindParam(":password", $param_password, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->bindParam(":email_verification", $param_email_verification, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            // Set parameters
            $param_username = $username;
            $param_email = $email;
            $param_email_verification = $email_verification;
            $param_password = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT); // Creates a password hash
            if ($stmt->execute()) {
                // Redirecion despues de registrar
                header("location: login.php");
            } else {
                echo "Algo no va bien, intentelo de nuevo o contacte con nosotros.";
            }
        }
        unset($stmt);
        unset($pdo);
    }
}
?>

<!-- Resto HTML -->
```

Otras cosas a considerar es que, a pesar de que parecería lo correcto, NO le debes hacer `trim()` ni al username ni al password. Si el usuario explicitamente colocó esos caracteres y tu sistema los logra registrar (porque los limpió con `trim()`), entonces le estás diciendo al usuario que su información tiene espacios en blanco, pero dentro de la BD ya no los tiene, por lo que no podrá loguearse con la información que el creía que habia escrito. Si no quieres esos caracteres, lo mejor sería indicarle al usuario que esos caracteres no son válidos y que los quite del `input`.

Comment: ¡Gracias @aeportugal! Me queda mucho por aprender y mejorar. Ahora lo miro con mas detalles